# How to retrieve/generate the PerfectLib.framework file for Perfect in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, perfect

While following Chris Manahan's tutorial for Perfect in Swift (http://www.chrismanahan.com/creating-a-web-service-swift-perfect), I was stuck on the part titled 'Linking Perfect'. Where exactly is the PerfectLib.framework file (see picture in tutorial) that Chris linked to the Cocoa Framework created earlier, and how can one retrieve it?

Note: I followed all of the instructions on https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect, including downloading OpenSSL and the Starter Project. I am running XCode 8 beta 3 with the Swift 3 toolchain, and have set the Xcode command line tools preference to XCode 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial was written for Xcode 7 / Swift 2.

If you want to use Perfect with Xcode 8, follow this:

1. Setup swiftenv to use the 08-04-a toolchain.
2. Clone https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate
3. Run `swift build`
4. run `swift package generate-xcodeproj`
5. Open the newly generated Xcode project
6. In your build settings for the project, add `$(PROJECT_DIR)` recursively to the library search paths
7. Edit the scheme for the application to use a custom build directory, and set that to whichever file path you cloned the template to.
8. From there you should be able to build and work in Xcode.

Comment: I should also mention at the time Xcode 8 is on beta 6, and you should also set command line tools to that in Locations in your Xcode preferences.